# data not appending with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

am receiving data via ajax from a url as JSON. the data is in UTF-8 characters (Urdu language charancters). they are coming ok and can be seen fine if shown in an alert box. but when they are appended to a tag using jquery , the tags remain empty . the code is as follows:

the main section tag:

```
<section class="row" id="news_detail">
   <img src="../images/loading.gif" alt="loading" id="loadingimg" class="img-responsive center-block" style="width: 300px; height: auto;" />

</section>   <!--loading img-->
```

the ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var id = getParameterByName('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/drupal/get/news',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data){

            $("#loadingimg").hide();

            if(data.status == true)
            {
                var titletag = $("<p>").addClass("article_title").append(this.title);

                var img = $("<img>").addClass("img-responsive center-block summary-image").attr("src", this.image_url).attr('alt',this.title);

                var p = $("<p>").addClass("article_body").html(this.body);
                   // alert(data.body);

                $(titletag).appendTo($("#news_detail"));
                $(img).appendTo($("#news_detail"));
                $(p).appendTo($("#news_detail"));
            }
            else if(data.status == false)
            {
                alert("The selected article could not be loaded. please try later");
            }

            $("#news_detail").append($("<div>").addClass("clear").html("&nbsp;"));
        },
        error: function()
        {
            $("#loadingimg").hide();
            alert("An error occured while retrieving the article. please try later");
        }
    });

});
```

as said, the json is coming fine and can be seen in an alert box (the data is mostly in UTF-8 codes of URDU language) . however, for clarification, the strcture of json is as follows:

```
{"status": true, "title": "abc", "image_url": "abc.jpg", "body": "text" }
```

the dynamic tags are appended to the DOM but without any data (i.e. empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing `this` in your success callback, but it should be `data`. I believe `this` in this context refers to the global object, so `this.title` and `this.body` are undefined, and therefore blank, values.

Comment: thank yu for the answer. it works. Another loss of copying code :) . the code was actually copied from another ajax call returning an array and i was traversing it with `data.each` function that is why it used `this` . Thank you again .. small thing was not coming to the mind :)